# MongoDB: Hard deletes vs Soft deletes, which is faster to execute?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a requirement where i need to delete documents which are of older version once a new newer documents are inserted for a given date. I have two ways to do this, one if soft delete where i set some flag like `isDeleted` to true and delete documents through a cleaning job. Other way is to hard delete the documents of older versions.

My only requirement is execution time as i have other operations to do along with the delete inside a transaction. I want to know whether updating a flag to delete is faster or deleting the records happens fastly. I also have indexes on the records, so want to know the performance impact on both operations considering the index updates required after both operation.

The records that are available to deletion will be around 10k and can grow to max 50k. Can someone please help me in understanding the performance impact of both operations ? please let me know if any additional details needs to be mentioned.

**Update**

I tried,

- profiling the updateMany and deleteMany by modifying 7k documents over index collection with the field considered for modification is indexed. Deletion took around 443ms and updateMany took 336ms. But i am not sure if this data is enough for the validation. currently, i am trying to add more documents and verify

Comment: Have you tried profiling your options to see which works best for you?

Comment: I am working on a script to duplicate the collection to try out both approaches on it, it is running, so i don't have results from them (yet). I want to to know the internal working in the mean time to see which is costlier approach

Comment: Is a delete always required, or could you update old documents with new fields/values?

Comment: No delete is always required, i need to stop consider older set of documents for a given date and consider only newly ingested documents for that date while reading. Whether i should invalidate them or delete is something that needs to be decided